# Apache returns index.html for all Angular script files

Tags: angular, apache, deployment, httpd.conf

I am deploying an angular app on apache but all the requests to retrieve scripts files (css, js) return index.html file which consequently doesn't render my site. What I have observed is that when I go to myapp.com/ on browser, the network section shows scripts loading (see image below) and my access logs on apache shows the same number of requests but none of them include the /[name of script requested]. It's as if all my requests where redirected to myapp.com/ and not myapp.com/style.css or myapp.com/main.js etc.
[image: network section of my browser]

Here is my httpd.conf file, I don't have .htaccess configured.

```
ServerRoot "/home/web000p1/inst001"
ServerName myapp.com
Listen 20080 ssl-cache
User "web000p1"
Group "docker"
DocumentRoot "/home/web000p1/inst001/htdocs"
# Tunning
Timeout 50
KeepAliveTimeout 8
StartServers 10
ServerLimit 256
MaxClients 50
MaxRequestsPerChild 70
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
</IfModule>
# LOG
LogLevel error
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
<IfModule logio_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>
CustomLog "/home/web000p1/inst001/logs/access_log" combined
ErrorLog "/home/web000p1/inst001/logs/error_log"
# RUN
PIDFile /home/web000p1/inst001/run/httpd.pid
Mutex file:/home/web000p1/inst001/run default ssl-cache
DefaultRuntimeDir /home/web000p1/inst001/run
# Sécurité
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature off
TraceEnable off
HostnameLookups off
TypesConfig /home/web000p1/inst001/conf/mime.types
DirectoryIndex index.html
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js

    
 <VirtualHost *:20080/*> 
  DocumentRoot /home/web000p1/inst001/htdocs
  <Directory /home/web000p1/inst001/htdocs>
      AllowOverride none
      RewriteEngine on
      
      # Don't rewrite files or directories
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]
      
      # Rewrite everything else to index.html
      # to allow html5 state links
      RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
```

The index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.7bcbf1db824f99b0640e.css"></head>
  <body mat-app-background>
    <app-content>Loading...</app-content>
  <script src="runtime.d4905fc349c3942af5be.js" defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.5e3328b0804724eb01ab.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills.4ad7f7addd9ca36babb2.js" defer></script>
  <script src="scripts.27a6881ffa719de73565.js" defer></script>
  <script src="main.879c1dd230effee66c71.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: It was ingress config issue, which was rerouting all my requests to /

Comment: could you please explan better what do you mean with config issue thanks